# DECODE function is not assigning Non IP values to NULL in procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, decode

I have a stored procedure where I am assigning as `IP1` sites as `IP` and if not `IP1` then it should be `NonIP`.

But when the sites are not `IP1` then decode is not working properly.

```
select  a.SAP_ID, decode (a.priority_site, 'IP1', 'IP', 'NonIP')  AS owners 
FROM
r4g_osp.enodeb a
LEFT JOIN app_wfm.wfm_candidate_status   st ON st.status = a.enodebstatus
WHERE a.sap_id in ('I-AP-NLGD-ENB-I001')
AND
a.scope IN (
    'EnodeB-Connected_Fibre',
    'EnodeB-Connected_MW'
 ) ;
```

Below is my output

[image: output]

please suggest how to set NonIP if values are null or blank

Comment: Your joins are incorrect i think. If there is no matching record in the r4g_osp.enodeb then your query will return nothing.

Comment: Your result is empty. You are selecting no sites, so there is no evaluation to make whether a site you show is IP or NonIP.

Comment: @Tejash: so which join i should try.. inner ?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner: what can be done in this scenario

Comment: Try right outer join and show us the result

Comment: still the same with right outer join also

Comment: What do you want to be done? You have written a query that can select sites with SAP IDs. For each site you determine whether it's IP or NonIP. This is working. Your select criteria however returns no sites, so there is no site that must be labeled IP or NonIP. If you expect rows to be returned, then check your criteria.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your outer join is not the problem.

The `DECODE` is not the problem.

Run this version of your code with the `DECODE` and the `LEFT JOIN` commented out.

```
select * -- a.SAP_ID, decode (a.priority_site, 'IP1', 'IP', 'NonIP')  AS owners 
FROM
r4g_osp.enodeb a
-- LEFT JOIN app_wfm.wfm_candidate_status   st ON st.status = a.enodebstatus
WHERE a.sap_id in ('I-AP-NLGD-ENB-I001')
AND
a.scope IN (
    'EnodeB-Connected_Fibre',
    'EnodeB-Connected_MW'
 ) ;
```

What is the result?

If you get no rows from your original query, you should get none from this version. The `DECODE` has no data to work with because no rows are returned.

The outer join does nothing because you are only accessing and filtering data from the ENODEB table. Since it is a left outer join, there is no additional filtering based on the status code.